# How to change date on bootstrap-timepicker update event?

Tags: javascript

I am working with the bootstrap time picker.I want to add increment the value of other textbox on the update event of bootstrap-timepicker.I am using following code but i am not able to increment the value of textbox.The value of txtStartTime=12:00 AM .With using following code when i change the value of textbox1 i got "nan" in my second textbox.

```
$('#txtStartTime').timepicker().on('changeTime.timepicker', function (e) {
 var edate = new Date(e.time.value);
 alert(e.time.value);                        "12:00 AM"
 var newDate = edate.setHours(edate.getHours() + 1);
 $("#txtEndTime").val(newDate);
 })
```

Answer (score 2):

Not sure why you are calling new date object.

e.time.hours would work fine to get the hours

```
$(function(){

$('#txtStartTime').timepicker().on('changeTime.timepicker', function (e) {

var newhour =(e.time.hours)+1;

var newTime = newhour + ':'+ e.time.minutes  + ' '+e.time.meridian;

$("#txtEndTime").val(newTime);
})

})
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/aor3f3j9/14/

Comment: when i added 12:00 AM it becomes 13 in my second text box but i want it 1:00 AM.  2:00 PM becomes 3 but i want 3:00 PM instead of 3 and so on....